# Toshiba Satellite A105 boots 10.10 from live CD and works fine. (everything works) when I install it I can't get past login

Tags: 10.10, gnome, video

When booting Ubuntu 10.10 from the live CD everything works Great.

Toshiba Satellite A105-S2071
Video card - ATI Xpress 200M

When I run the 10.10 installation routine it installs without errors. When I reboot I get to the login screen. I then login.  It makes the boot sound and then I am left with a background screen with a moveable cursor an nothing else.   I have no panels, no icons, nothing.

If I boot into safe mode the Gnome shell loads.

I suspect its a video issue but I don't know where to go from here

Answer (score 1):

Adding nomodeset to grub fixed the problem

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the following line from

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Save the file. Reboot and you should be good to go.

([source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132))